# Fill dates according another date using sas

Tags: sas

I have three columns in my dataset: `ID`, `Date1` and `Date2`. I need to fill the column `Date1` according to `Date2`. In other words, if `Date1` is older then `Date2` then `Date1` will be the same value.

My original data is:

```
ID  |Date1     | Date2
84  |          |13JAN2015
84  |12NOV2014 |05FEB2015
84  |12NOV2014 |07FEB2015
106 |          |13JAN2015
106 |09MAY2014 |05FEB2015
106 |09MAY2014 |07FEB2015
106 |09MAY2014 |09MAR2015
153 |16JAN2015 |08OCT2015
153 |16JAN2015 |12NOV2015
155 |          |13JAN2015
155 |01JUN2014 |05FEB2015
155 |25APR2015 |12NOV2015
155 |25APR2015 |28NOV2015
```

And I want to obtain this result:

```
ID  |Date1     | Date2
84  |12NOV2014 |13JAN2015
84  |12NOV2014 |05FEB2015
84  |12NOV2014 |07FEB2015
106 |09MAY2014 |13JAN2015
106 |09MAY2014 |05FEB2015
106 |09MAY2014 |07FEB2015
106 |09MAY2014 |09MAR2015
153 |16JAN2015 |08OCT2015
153 |16JAN2015 |12NOV2015
155 |01JUN2014 |13JAN2015
155 |01JUN2014 |05FEB2015
155 |25APR2015 |12NOV2015
155 |25APR2015 |28NOV2015
```

Assuming `Date1` is the birth date and `Date2` is the collection information date, then all information that was collected after birth (for the same ID) must belong to the same birth date, thus filling in the blanks.

I've tried to use an `IF` statement, but it didn't work.
Someone could help me?

Comment: How do you get form `Date1=""` to `Date1="12/nov/14"` for the first record ? There is something you are not telling or the example is wrong. (Also it would help if you provided your data hardcoded in a datastep.)

Comment: Assuming Date1 is the birth date and Date2 is the collection information date, then all information that was collected after birth (for the same ID) must belong to the same birth date, thus filling in the blanks.

Comment: Do you have the name of the date format you are using here?

Comment: Sas format: `Date9.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the lag() function which allows you to read the value of the previous record in the data step loop.

```
data have;
    infile datalines delimiter='|';
    length Date1$10 Date2$10;
    input ID  Date1 $ Date2 $;
    datalines;
84  |          |13JAN2015
84  |12NOV2014 |05FEB2015
84  |12NOV2014 |07FEB2015
106 |          |13JAN2015
106 |09MAY2014 |05FEB2015
106 |09MAY2014 |07FEB2015
106 |09MAY2014 |09MAR2015
153 |16JAN2015 |08OCT2015
153 |16JAN2015 |12NOV2015
155 |          |13JAN2015
155 |01JUN2014 |05FEB2015
155 |25APR2015 |12NOV2015
155 |25APR2015 |28NOV2015
;
run;

*** convert to dates;
data have;
    set have;
    format d2 d1 Date9.;
    *Date1 = COMPRESS( tranwrd(Date1,'/',''),,'s');
    d1 = input(Date1,Date9.);
    *Date2 = COMPRESS( tranwrd(Date2,'/',''),,'s');
    d2 = input(Date2,Date9.);
    rename d1=Date1 d2=Date2;
    drop Date1 Date2;
    run;

*** sort;
proc sort data=have out=want;
    by id descending Date2;
    run;quit;

*** if missing then fill in previous value;
data want;
    set want;
    lagDate1=lag(Date1);
    if Date1=. then Date1=lagDate1;
    drop lagDate1;
    run;

*** sort back to normal;
proc sort data=want;
    by id Date2;
    run;quit;
```

1. sort the data
2. if missing then copy the previous value
3. sort back to normal

> You might want to add a rule to verify that `ID` is the same as previous record before copying the date from it.